Why XSLT code with multiple for-loop on XSLT 3.0
Good day. I need an your assistance. I'm not frequent XSLT developer
I developed XSLT which I expected to get output, however my XSLT not provide expected way.
Could you please give me your valuable suggestions.
XML Input:
<Order>
    <OrderTypes>
        <SalesOrder>3000016154</SalesOrder>
        <SoldToParty>1</SoldToParty>
        <ItemPartner>
            <PartnerTypes>
                <PFunction>SH</PFunction>
                <Customer>A</Customer>
                <Address>
                    <AddressType>
                        <Name>Test_FinalCustomer1</Name>
                        <Address>Test_FinalCustomer1</Address>
                    </AddressType>
                </Address>
            </PartnerTypes>
            <PartnerTypes>
                <PFunction>FC</PFunction>
                <Customer>B</Customer>
                <Address>
                    <AddressType>
                        <Name>Test_FinalCustomer2</Name>
                        <Address>Test_FinalCustomer2</Address>
                    </AddressType>
                </Address>
            </PartnerTypes>
        </ItemPartner>
        <ItemTypes>
            <Types>
                <Unit>KG</Unit>
                <NetAmount>5000.00</NetAmount>
                <PricingElementsType>
                    <PrElementType>
                        <RateValue>2000</RateValue>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <Type>PR00</Type>
                    </PrElementType>
                    <PrElementType>
                        <RateValue>3000</RateValue>
                        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                        <Type>PR01</Type>
                    </PrElementType>
                </PricingElementsType>
            </Types>
            <Types>
                <Unit>ML</Unit>
                <NetAmount>6000.00</NetAmount>
                <PricingElementsType>
                    <PrElementType>
                        <RateValue>4000</RateValue>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <Type>PR00</Type>
                    </PrElementType>
                    <PrElementType>
                        <RateValue>2000</RateValue>
                        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                        <Type>PR01</Type>
                    </PrElementType>
                </PricingElementsType>
            </Types>
        </ItemTypes>
    </OrderTypes>
</Order>

XSLT Code
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <xsl:for-each select="OrderTypes">
            <data>
                <xsl:if test="SalesOrder">
                    <VBELN>
                        <xsl:value-of select="SalesOrder"/>
                    </VBELN>
                </xsl:if>
                <HEAD>
                    <xsl:if test="SalesOrder">
                        <VBELN>
                            <xsl:value-of select="SalesOrder"/>
                        </VBELN>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="SoldToParty">
                        <KUNNR_AG>
                            <xsl:value-of select="SoldToParty"/>
                        </KUNNR_AG>
                    </xsl:if>
                
                <xsl:for-each select="//PartnerTypes">
                    <xsl:if test="PFunction = 'SH'">
                        <xsl:if test=" Customer">
                    <KUNNR_SH>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Customer"/>
                    </KUNNR_SH>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:for-each select="//AddressType">
                    <xsl:if test="Address">
                        <Address>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Address"/>
                        </Address>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Types">
            <HEAD_ENTRIES>
                <xsl:if test="Unit">
                    <UNIT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Unit"/>
                    </UNIT>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="NetAmount">
                    <NET_AMOUNT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NetAmount"/>
                    </NET_AMOUNT>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:for-each select="//PrElementType">
                
                <xsl:if test="Type ='PR00'">
                    <xsl:if test="RateValue">
                        <RATE_VALUE>
                            <xsl:value-of select="RateValue"/>
                        </RATE_VALUE>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="Quantity">
                        <QUANTITY>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/>
                        </QUANTITY>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>   
                </xsl:for-each>
            </HEAD_ENTRIES>
            
        </xsl:for-each>
        </HEAD>
    </data>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Expected Output:
<data xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
      xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
      xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global"
      xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
      xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
   <VBELN>3000016154</VBELN>
   <HEAD>
      <VBELN>3000016154</VBELN>
      <KUNNR_AG>1</KUNNR_AG>
      <KUNNR_SH>A</KUNNR_SH>
      <Address>Test_FinalCustomer1</Address>
      <HEAD_ENTRIES>
         <UNIT>KG</UNIT>
         <NET_AMOUNT>5000.00</NET_AMOUNT>
         <RATE_VALUE>2000</RATE_VALUE>
         <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
      </HEAD_ENTRIES>
      <HEAD_ENTRIES>
         <UNIT>ML</UNIT>
         <NET_AMOUNT>6000.00</NET_AMOUNT>
         <RATE_VALUE>4000</RATE_VALUE>
         <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
      </HEAD_ENTRIES>
   </HEAD>
</data>

Could you please give me your valuable suggestions. Thank you
With Best Regards,
Sateesh N

Please ask a specific question about a specific problem, and reduce the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem - see: [mcve].

Hi Michael,
Thank you for your response. Really tried my best to reduce my code., my actual problem was , which I couldn't able implement the right for loop conditions due to multiple sub nodes.

Your main issue are the XPath's starting with //. They will find all elements in reh document. To use the context add a . in front of them: .//

Excellent Siebe, Thank you so much. your input resolved all my problem :)

as Input suggested by Siebe Jongebloed, my problem has been resolved to use the context add a . in front of them: .//
Thank you very much for this community.
